# JSF 2: h:link and getrowdata

Tags: jsf-2, jpa-2.0, glassfish-3

If I have a `h:dataTable` in **books.xhtml** providing a list of records and I want to view a particular record, then add or edit that record, currently I have this:

```
<h:dataTable #{BookBean.books}" var="books">
   <h:link outcome="bookview" value="#{books[1]}">
      <f:param name="id" value="#{books[2]}" />
   </h:link>
</h:dataTable>
```

I found out that I need to include `<f:param>` in order to show the CSS status of clicked link; otherwise if I don't have `<f:param>`, every time I clicked on a link rendered by h:link tags in the codes above, all links are changed to CSS clicked status.

Also, I read somewhere about the `getrowdata()` but I haven't been able to get it work. Is this a better alternative to using `<f:param>`?

I have tried the `getrowdata()` method in my BookBean class as followed:

```
private DataModel<BookModel> books;
private BookModel currentBook;

public String view()
{
     currentBook = books.getRowData();
     return "bookview";
}
```

and in bookview.xhtml I have this:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{BookBean.view}" var="item">
    ... // render content here
<h:dataTable>
```

but I get an error about the property not found. Sorry for asking this question but I still don't understand yet some of the powerful features of JSF 2. Can some expert who understand the usage of `h:link` and `getrowdata` please explain to me in layman terms or perhaps with some basic code example. Thank you.

**UPDATE:**
Changed classes based on @BalusC suggestions below. **BookModel** class is:

```
@Entity
public class BookModel implements Serializable
{
   private Long id;
   private String title;
   private String author;   

   // getters and setters here
 }
```

The **BookService** class looks like this:

```
@Stateless
public class BookService
{
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "persistentUnit")
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    public BookModel create() {
       return new BookModel();
    }

    public void delete(BookModel bookModel) {
       bookModel = entityManager.merge(bookModel);
       entityManager.remove(bookModel);
    }

    public BookModel update(BookModel bookModel) {
       return entityManager.merge(bookModel);
    }

    public BookModel find(Long id) {
       return entityManager.find(BookModel.class, id);
    }
}
```

The **BookBean** class is:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "bookBean")
@RequestScoped
public class BookBean implements Serializable
{
    @EJB
    private BookService bookService;

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{param.id}")
    private Long id;

    private DataModel<BookModel> books;
    private BookModel currentBook;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        currentBook = bookService.find(id);
    }

    public BookModel getCurrentBook() {
       return currentBook;
    }

    public void setCurrentBook(BookModel currentBook) {
       this.currentBook = currentBook;
    }
 }
```

Running the BookBean class above caused this error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: WEB9031: WebappClassLoader unable to load resource [org.apache.openjpa.util.LongId], because it has not yet been started, or was already stopped`. This is where I'm stuck at the moment.

FYI: My dev environment is Glassfish 3.1, Apache OpenJPA 2.1 and JSF 2.1.0 (that comes bundled with Glassfish)

Comment: I have no utter idea what you mean with "CSS status" and how exactly that is an issue. CSS is just a styling language which should not affect any JSF functionality in any way. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @BalusC: The **CSS Status** I mentioned above is to do with a:visited. I hope this clears up any misunderstanding. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two flaws in the code:

- The `h:link` fires a GET request, not a POST request. The `DataModel#getRowData()` is not useful here either since you cannot attach bean actions to components which fire a GET request.
- The `<h:dataTable value="#{BookBean.view}">` with `public String view()` makes no sense. The datatable's value has got to be a collection of items, not a bean action method.

---

I understand that you want a GET link on every book item in the table which points to some detail page about the book item. Fix the detail page as follows:

`bookview.xhtml`

```
<h:outputText value="#{bookBean.currentBook.id}" />
<h:outputText value="#{bookBean.currentBook.author}" />
<h:outputText value="#{bookBean.currentBook.title}" />
...
```

And the `BookBean` as follows:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public BookBean {

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{param.id}")
    private Long id;

    private BookModel currentBook;

    @PostConstruct 
    public void init() {
        currentBook = bookDAO.find(id);
    }

    // ...
}
```

The `@ManagedProperty` will set the GET request parameter. The `@PostConstruct` will preload the right book based on the parameter.

Please note that this has nothing to do with POST-Redirect-GET pattern.

Comment: Great answer! Although the question was very unclear. @user463053 - Have a look at BaluC's http://balusc.blogspot.com/2010/06/benefits-and-pitfalls-of-viewscoped.html post for an excellent example of CRUD. Especially for the correct use of getRowData(). @BaluC - Btw, with the CSS status I suppose he meant the anchor tags getting the a:visited style applied to all of his links.

Comment: @BalusC: Yes, you're spot on about what I want to achieve. I tried your suggested changes above and I have encountered this error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: WEB9031: WebappClassLoader unable to load resource [org.apache.openjpa.util.LongId], because it has not yet been started, or was already stopped`. Sorry I should have mentioned I use OpenJPA in my original post. I have updated my original post with more info to show you what I am attempting to do.

Comment: @BalusC: I have removed the **post-redirect-get** tag and updated the post with other tags which I hope are more closely related to my question at hand.

Comment: As per your edit, clean/rebuild/redeploy/restart your webapp/server.

Comment: @BalusC: I close Eclipse, delete the build directory of the project, delete the project directory under Glassfish's `eclipseApps` directory, start Eclipse, build the project, start Glassfish - but still the same error. As per my update above, `id` is the primary key which I think is required by the `EntityManager#find` method. Could this be a OpenJPA issue? I also did a search on the error message, but nothing useful came up.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. This issue is beyond the scope of the question. Run the debugger or add poor man's `System.out.print` statements. Is the `@PostConstruct` invoked? Is the URL parameter been set? If so, then your question is technically answered. As to the new problem, I'd consider to press `Ask Question` button.

Comment: @BalusC: The @PostContruct is invoked and the value returned for the `id` parameter from the resulting is correct. It falls over when JSF tries to render the page. When I was in debug mode `bookview` renders a blank table - but when I run in normal mode I get the above error. I have updated the original post showing the getter/setter methods for `currentBook`. Is this correctle defined?

Comment: The particular `IllegalStateException` is not related to JSF. I suspect OpenJPA. Just wondering, why are you favoring it over Glassfish-bundled EclipseLink?

Comment: @BalusC: Does the `EntityManager#find` method requires a primary key column for the second parameter? What happens if I want to pass a hashed value for the `id` parameter instead of the primary key of the table. Do I then need to made the hash column in the table a key as well? If that's the case, then the `EntityManage#find` method is very restrictive IMHO.

Comment: In essence not. At least, that's my experience with Glassfish-bundled EclipseLink.

Comment: @BalusC: My boss is a fervent Apache supporter and he insisted that I implement the webapp with OpenJPA instead of EclipseLink or Hibernate. Sorry, my hands are tied, but I have tried to influence his thinking without success -:)

Comment: I googled a bit on the exception message "java.lang.IllegalStateException: WEB9031: WebappClassLoader unable to load resource" and it seems to be more Glassfish specific and that the classpath is good messed up. Probably you've duplicate libs in the classpath and/or libs at wrong places.

Comment: @BalusC: Thanks for all your valuable responses to this post. I'll mark your initial response as answered. I'll see if I can chase this issue with the Apache boys and see what they say. Or, ask another question here regarding the above error with OpenJPA and hope another person has stumbled across this before and have a solution for it -;). Also, I have a workaround that does not use the `EntityManager#find` method and it works but I would prefer the JPA method for future supportability and maintenance...

Comment: @BalusC: I don't have any lib in the WAR file. I have saved `openjpa-all-2.1.0.jar` to `\glassfish\lib` directory. Is this correct? The JSF 2.1.0 libs are under the default `\glassfish\modules` directory that comes with Glassfish 3.1.

Comment: @BalusC: I just did some testing and it looks like the `openjpa-all-2.1.0.jar` has to be under the `\glassfish\lib` directory. In that case, I'll try to set up EclipseLink and see if I will experience similar issue as OpenJPA...