# JSF 2 OpenJPA 2 Glassfish 3.1 WEB9031 Error

Tags: jsf-2, jpa-2.0, glassfish-3

I got this error which according to Apache Support is an issue relating with Glassfish rather than OpenJPA:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: WEB9031: WebappClassLoader unable to load resource [org.apache.openjpa.util.LongId], because it has not yet been started, or was already stopped
```

The stacktrace is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WEB9031: WebappClassLoader unable to load resource [org.apache.openjpa.util.LongId], because it has not yet been started, or was already stopped
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1410)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1368)
    at com.ckd.model.BookModel.pcNewObjectIdInstance(BookModel.java)
    at org.apache.openjpa.enhance.PCRegistry.newObjectId(PCRegistry.java:138)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.processRegisteredClass(MetaDataRepository.java:1693)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.processRegisteredClasses(MetaDataRepository.java:1643)
    ... 112 more
```

Has anyone come across this before and how to resolve it? I have been stuck on this issue for the last several days.

Another of my post related to this issue can be found here: [JSF 2: h:link and getrowdata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585017/jsf-2-hlink-and-getrowdata).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above error relates to a problem with the OpenJPA enhancer. When you execute Sun's JDK the OpenJPA's dynamic enhancer starts by default. This action, in turn, stuffs up Glassfish's classloader class - hence, the **WEB9031** error.

For those who experience this same issue, a simple workaround is to do the enhancement at build time - which I did in ANT with `org.apache.openjpa.ant.PCEnhancerTask` - and add this property to your **persistence.xml** to shut off the dynamic enhancer: `<property name="openjpa.DynamicEnhancementAgent" value="false"/>`.

Also, it wouldn't hurt to throw this in your **persistence.xml** as well `<property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="unsupported" />`.