# Call to JPA (OpenJPA) within remote EJB fails the first time after deploy of application

Tags: glassfish, ejb, java-ee-6, openjpa

I'm having a strange problem in our EJBs that are running on a Glassfish 3.1 using OpenJPA.

Firste there's our Enterprise-Application 'businessBeans' that handles all the JPA/Entity-Stuff. It offers some EJBs that other Apps can use through the remote interface.

Now my App (that's not bundled in the same .ear) is trying to access those businessBeans through

`@EJB(lookup = TaskRemote.JNDI)
    private TaskRemote taskRemote;`

So far so good, and I can call the Methods defined in that Interface

But when I call a Method for the first time after a redeploy that should load a Entity from the DB like this:

```
List<BigInteger> tasks = this.taskRemote.getMeSomeStuffFromDb(someArgument);
```

I get an exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WEB9031: WebappClassLoader unable to load resource [org.apache.openjpa.util.StringId], because it has not yet been started, or was already stopped
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1401)
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1359)
at ch.bs.zid.egov.business.entity.egov.SystemEnvironment.pcNewObjectIdInstance(SystemEnvironment.java)
at org.apache.openjpa.enhance.PCRegistry.newObjectId(PCRegistry.java:142)
at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.processRegisteredClass(MetaDataRepository.java:1694)
at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.processRegisteredClasses(MetaDataRepository.java:1644)
... 162 more
```

**If I do the exact same call again, it works ... until I make another redeploy**

Now a workaround for the problem I'm currently using is to just make a call in the @postConstruct Method of the calling EJB to be done with the failing first call...

```
@PostConstruct
private void workaround()
{
    try
    {
        this.taskRemote.getMeSomeStuffFromDb(someArgument);
    }
    catch (EJBException e)
    {
        this.logger.logSystemInfo("Excected Exception in Workaround");
    }        
}
```

but that's not exactly pretty ;)

Does anybody have an idea what causes this behaviour or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Solution >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622436/jsf-2-openjpa-2-glassfish-3-1-web9031-error

Comment: @RaviTrivedi Thx for the comment, but it seems that, although the error message is the same, the cause isn't. We tried modifying the persistance.xml as explaned but to no avail. And as stated, in our case, the error appears only on the first request after a deploy of the application.